# Artifactory docker login /v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found

Tags: docker, kubernetes-helm, artifactory, nginx-ingress

We are running Artifactory 7.35.2 on AWS EKS v1.21, using helm chart to deploy. We are also using nginx-ingress for all our domains in the cluster with NLB.

Issue we are having now is i am getting error when trying to do docker login:

```
❯ docker login artifactory.example.com 
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://artifactory.example.com/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found
```

I went to `Artifactory > HTTP Settings` and used both subdomain and repository path with same result, using Tomcat as Server Provider. When using Nginx as provider, i get:

```
Login did not succeed, error: Error response from daemon: Get "https://artifactory.example.com/v2/": received unexpected HTTP status: 503 Service Unavailable
```

The ingress code in helm chart is from:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Helm+Charts+for+Advanced+Users#HelmChartsforAdvancedUsers-ArtifactoryAdvancedOptions

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  defaultBackend:
    enabled: false
  hosts:
    - artifactory.example.com
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/ingress.provider: ingress-nginx
    ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "600"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      rewrite ^/(v2)/token /artifactory/api/docker/null/v2/token;
      rewrite ^/(v2)/([^\/]*)/(.*) /artifactory/api/docker/$2/$1/$3;
```

Although, `rewrite ^/(v2)/([^\/]*)/(.*) /artifactory/api/docker/$2/$1/$3;` is currently giving me error in helm:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: cannot patch "artifactory" with kind Ingress: admission webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io" denied the request: nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet annotation contains invalid word \
```

I changed it to `rewrite ^/(v2)/(.*)/(.*) /artifactory/api/docker/$2/$1/$3;` but still getting same 404 error.

Has anyone else ran into similar issue that can point me in right direction?

Comment: Update: I resolved the issue with 

rewrite ^/(v2)/([^\/]*)/(.*) /artifactory/api/docker/$2/$1/$3;

by upgrading ingress-nginx to 1.1.2. I believe that issue was resolved, starting from 1.1.0.